# Bug in my Kafka Producer class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Im very new to Kafka and started to working on the Producer-Consumer model.
I wrote a program for Kafka producer which will read a table from MySQL and I'm reading those messages on the command prompt.
The problem is that I could only see data from the last column of the table.

MySQL Table structure and data:

```
+----------+---------+----------------+
| dept     | empName | salary(double) |
+----------+---------+----------------+
| Engg     | Fred    |   2000         |
| Engg     | Bob     |   3000         |
| Engg     | Joe     |   1000         |
| Arts     | Jack    |   5000         |
| Commerce | Jill    |   2400         |
| Arts     | James   |   3000         |
| Commerce | Rob     |   8700         |
+----------+---------+----------------+
```

Kafka Producer class:

```
package com.kafka.producer;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class KafkaMySqlProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement pstmnt;
        ResultSet rs;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zk.connect", "localhost:2181");
        props.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("metadata.broker.list","localhost:9092");
        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
        Producer producer = new Producer(config);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","cloudera");
            pstmnt = con.prepareStatement("select * from department");
            rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString(1);
                String department = rs.getString(2);
                String salary = " " + rs.getDouble(3);
                producer.send(new KeyedMessage("dbrec", name, department, salary));
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

output from my consumer:

```
[cloudera@quickstart kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0]$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic dbrec --from-beginning
[2017-06-18 10:23:22,428] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {dbrec=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-06-18 10:23:22,628] WARN The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members in the group console-consumer-33197 : [dbrec]  (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

 2000.0
 3000.0
 1000.0
 5000.0
 2400.0
 3000.0
 8700.0
```

I'm just getting the data from last column of the table.
Can anyone tell me what is the mistake I'm doing here?

Comment: If you are starting a new project with Kafka, it's better to start using the new producer and consumer classes. I see that you are using the older one with producer connecting to Zookeeper for getting information about brokers and not directly to one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of the `KeyedMessage` constructor with 4 arguments is the actual message.

The class doesn't just accept a list of all your values.

Specifically, the parameters you provided are `(topic, key, partKey, message)`. You only consume `message` from `topic`

Comment: Okay.. Corrected it like this.
producer.send(new KeyedMessage("dbrec", name + " " + department + " " + salary)); and is working now.

Comment: Also I see deprecated messages for these two lines.
  ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
  Producer producer = new Producer(config);
Could you tell me what are the new options for those methods, so that I can implement them.

Comment: Not sure, but the JavaDoc could probably answer that for you

Comment: Okay. Will check JavaDoc